# Custom ArrayAdapter buttons, getting item at position

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an app which shows a list of items with a custom ArrayAdapter. Listeners can be set up to allow users to tap a row to open another activity to process the item referred to by that row, or to long press to delete an item. Here's an example of one of these listeners, which is defined in the corresponding ListActivity:

```
// single tap selects an item for viewing
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id)
  {
    Project p = projects.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListProjectActivity.this, CountingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("project_id",p.id);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

However, I've found that long pressing is something that many users don't find intuitive, and so I'd prefer to put a button into the custom layout for each row and then attach a listener to the TextView in the row (to represent the single tap to load another activity) and to the button (for deleting). So, I put listeners like this into the ArrayAdapter itself:

```
public class ProjectListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Project>
{
     // set up constructor and project holder
     //....

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     {
        View row = convertView;
        ProjectHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ProjectHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.deleteProject = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteProject);

            holder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener);
            holder.deleteProject.setOnClickListener(mOnDeleteClickListener);
            // the button and textview above could be tagged with position, but that
            // re-sets as the rows are re-used

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ProjectHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(project.name);

        return row;
      }

      private View.OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        Project p = null; // how can I get this here?
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CountingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("project_id",p.id);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
      }
     };

     // the delete listener is similar

   }
```

The difficulty here is that I need to get the Project object associated with the ArrayAdapter at the position tapped, so I can either delete the object or open a new activity to process it. Can anyone suggest how I might get the object associated with the row tapped when using a listener of that sort, please?

Comment: Use `holder.deleteProject.setTag(position)`(outside of the `if (convertView ==...` block). In the `OnClickItemListener` you can then use the passed view to get the position: `(Integer)v.getTag()`. If the object isn't too big you could pass it directly through `setTag()`.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that position keeps being re-set as the rows are re-used. If there are 20 projects in the database yet the device's screen only shows 8 at a time, then when a user taps on the 9th project the 1st is the one actually loaded.

Comment: The `ListView` only recycles the row views not the data it holds. You use the position to get the data from the list of data you have(or another data source) in the OnClickListener.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had some thing similar but I was setting the tags in the convertview == ... block, which was presumably the cause of my trouble. As the project is a small object (two longs and two Strings) then passing it as a tag seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a class that implements `OnClickListener`, a pass the object to the constructor:

```
 private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
     private Project mProject;
     public MyOnClickListener(Project p) {
           mProject = p;
     }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CountingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("project_id",mProject.id);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
      }
}


      getView(...) {

        // other logic

        holder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener((Project)getItem(position)));
        holder.txtTitle.setText(project.name);

        return row;
      }
```

Comment: This looks like a very interesting method, but I can't see how to get Project p to pass into the MyOnClick listener in the first place. The position value in getView() is never higher than the number of rows which can fit on the screen and therefore large numbers of projects can't be accommodated. For example, if there are 20 in the database and 8 on the screen then a user tapping the 9th is shown the 1st.

Comment: you are talking about view's recycling. Dataset will not be touched by the system

Comment: Indeed, it seems that I was getting the position in the wrong place and so the view recycling was causing me trouble. It looks like I've fixed that now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ProjectListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Project>
{
     // set up constructor and project holder
     //....

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     {
        View row = convertView;
        ProjectHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ProjectHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.deleteProject = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteProject);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ProjectHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(project.name);


 holder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        // you can get the PROJECT refrence here
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CountingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("project_id",p.id);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
      }
     };

     // the delete listener is similar

        return row;
      }



   }
```

Comment: Getting the project reference is the difficult part - if I only have v from the onClick function there doesn't seem to be any way to track that back to a Project in List<Project> projects.